# How to prevent mockserver forward from adding extra headers?

Tags: java, http, forward, mockserver

I am redirecting requests to real services with

```
HiveContextTest(ClientAndServer mockServer) {
    this.mockServer = mockServer;
}

...

my test {
    mockServer.when(
        HttpRequest.request()
            .withPath("/hive-tables.*")
    ).forward(
        forward()
            .withHost("real.service.host")
            .withPort(443)
            .withScheme(HttpForward.Scheme.HTTPS)
    );
}
```

Unfortunately, this forward adds header with old host

```
curl -v 'https://old.host/hive-tables...' ...  -H 'Host: old.host'
```

and this confuses the service.

Is it possible to prevent the `Host` header to be added?